# Python 2 tkinter, a loan window appears when it has not been called for

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, window, messagebox

I have come across an issue with using the tkinter message box, when a user of my application presses the English flag and then goes to Log-out in the top right hand corner a message box appears but also another box appears with the window title 'tk', I have not made or called any such window so my theory is that the window is coming from some place with the message box or maybe its something I have mistakenly done in my code which I cant see.

here is my code below;

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as box
Title_Text = 25
Title_Font = "Courier"
Font = 'Ariel'
Rest_Text = 16
Background_Colour = 'Light blue'




def EngFlag():
    print('Hello world')

def LogOut1():
    response = box.askquestion ('?', 'Are You Sure?')
    if response == 'yes':
        try:
         window.destroy()
        except:
         Eng_window.destroy()




def back1():
    Home_Screen()


def Home_Screen():
    global window
    window = Tk()
    window.geometry('1366x768')
    window.configure(background = Background_Colour)
    window.title('Local Languages Learning System')
    window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

    try:
        Eng_window.destroy()
    except:
        pass



    Title1 = Label(window, text = 'Local Languages Home Screen', bg = Background_Colour)
    Title1.config(font=("Courier", Title_Text))
    Title1.pack()
    Title1.place(y = 1, x = 450)


    Question_Label = Label(window, text = 'Please Pick The Language You Wish To Learn', bg = Background_Colour)
    Question_Label.config(font=(Font, Rest_Text))
    Question_Label.pack()
    Question_Label.place(y = 200, x = 495)

    Log_Out = Button(window, text = 'Log-Out', height = 1, width = 8, command = LogOut1)
    Log_Out.pack()
    Log_Out.place(y = 5, x = 1290)


    help_btn = Button(window, text = 'Help', height = 1, width = 8, command = None)
    help_btn.pack()
    help_btn.place(y = 45, x = 1290)



    English_Flag = PhotoImage(file = 'EnglishFlag.gif')
    English_Flag_btn = Button(window, image = English_Flag, command = English_Home_Screen)
    English_Flag_btn.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 10)
    English_Flag_btn.place(y = 350, x = 300)


    Polish_Flag = PhotoImage(file = 'PolishFlag.gif')
    Polish_Flag_btn = Button(window, image = Polish_Flag, command = EngFlag)
    Polish_Flag_btn.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 10)
    Polish_Flag_btn.place(y = 350, x = 600)


    Italian_Flag = PhotoImage(file = 'ItalianFlag.gif')
    Italian_Flag_btn = Button(window, image = Italian_Flag, command = None)
    Italian_Flag_btn.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 10)
    Italian_Flag_btn.place(y = 350, x = 900)



    window.mainloop()

def English_Home_Screen():
    global Eng_window
    Eng_window = Tk()
    Eng_window.geometry('1366x768')
    Eng_window.configure(background = Background_Colour)
    Eng_window.title('Local Languages Learning System')
    Eng_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    window.destroy()


    Title1 = Label(Eng_window, text = 'Local Languages\nEnglish Home Screen', bg = Background_Colour)
    Title1.config(font=("Courier", Title_Text))
    Title1.pack()
    Title1.place(y = 1, x = 450)


    Log_Out = Button(Eng_window, text = 'Log-Out', height = 1, width = 8, command = LogOut1)
    Log_Out.pack()
    Log_Out.place(y = 5, x = 1290)


    Back = Button(Eng_window, text = 'Back', height = 1, width = 8, command = back1)
    Back.pack()
    Back.place(y = 5, x = 1210)



    help_btn = Button(Eng_window, text = 'Help', height = 1, width = 8, command = None)
    help_btn.pack()
    help_btn.place(y = 45, x = 1290)


    Play_all = Button(Eng_window, text = 'Play All Games', height = 2, width = 20, command = None)
    Play_all.pack()
    Play_all.place(y = 100, x = 320)


    Multiple_Choice = Button(Eng_window, text = 'Play Multiple Choice Game', height = 2, width = 20, command = None)
    Multiple_Choice.pack()
    Multiple_Choice.place(y = 100, x = 510)


    Picture = Button(Eng_window, text = 'Play Picture Game', height = 2, width = 20, command = None)
    Picture.pack()
    Picture.place(y = 100, x = 700)


    Memory = Button(Eng_window, text = 'Play Memory Game', height = 2, width = 20, command = None)
    Memory.pack()
    Memory.place(y = 100, x = 890)


    LeaderBoard = Button(Eng_window, text = 'LeaderBoard', height = 2, width = 20, command = None)
    LeaderBoard.pack()
    LeaderBoard.place(y = 160, x = 600)


Home_Screen()
```

Apologies for it being so long but to actually see the problem you have to have all the code. Any help or fixies would be great.

Comment: No, we haven't have to have the whole code, especially not the image parts.

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You do not need to provide all the code. Just enough that shows the problem. In doing so you often find the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now there are several issues with your code and some I will address.

First off what you are trying to do is very complicated when using a Non-OOP method. I have re-written your code as OOP to provide some ease of use and readability.

For the most part you should avoid using `global` the easiest way to do this is to use class attributes instead. This allows for you to have a variable that can be seen by any method within the class.

Some helpful tips:

Do not import tkinter twice.
Instead of doing:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as box
```

Do this instead:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
```

Your `Try/Except` function will not work as you expect as `Eng_window.destroy()` will not return an error regardless of if the window is there or not. So it will always attempt to destroy `Eng_window` and never `window`

Instead do this:

```
# This will check if the instance of Eng_self_window exist first.
if tk.Toplevel.winfo_exists(self.Eng_self_window):
    self.Eng_self_window.destroy()
else:
    self.window.destroy()
```

Let me know if you have any questions on the class set up.
It can be done using global's but its not as clean and harder to deal with.

Here I have moved your code into a class and rearranged some stuff.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class Home_Screen(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.Title_Text = 25
        self.Title_Font = "Courier"
        self.Font = 'Ariel'
        self.Rest_Text = 16
        self.Background_Colour = 'Light blue'

        self.window = parent
        self.window.geometry('1366x768')
        self.window.configure(background = self.Background_Colour)
        self.window.title('Local Languages Learning System')
        #self.window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        Title1 = tk.Label(self.window, text = 'Local Languages Home Screen', bg = self.Background_Colour)
        Title1.config(font=("Courier", self.Title_Text))
        Title1.pack()
        Title1.place(y = 1, x = 450)

        Question_Label = tk.Label(self.window, text = 'Please Pick The Language You Wish To Learn', bg = self.Background_Colour)
        Question_Label.config(font=(self.Font, self.Rest_Text))
        Question_Label.pack()
        Question_Label.place(y = 200, x = 495)

        Log_Out = tk.Button(self.window, text = 'Log-Out', height = 1, width = 8, command = self.LogOut1)
        Log_Out.pack()
        Log_Out.place(y = 5, x = 1290)

        help_btn = tk.Button(self.window, text = 'Help', height = 1, width = 8, command = None)
        help_btn.pack()
        help_btn.place(y = 45, x = 1290)

        self.English_Flag = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'EnglishFlag.gif')
        self.English_Flag_btn = tk.Button(self.window, image = self.English_Flag, command = self.English_Home_Screen)
        self.English_Flag_btn.pack(side = tk.LEFT, padx = 10)
        self.English_Flag_btn.place(y = 350, x = 300)

        self.Polish_Flag = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'PolishFlag.gif')
        self.Polish_Flag_btn = tk.Button(self.window, image = self.Polish_Flag, command = self.EngFlag)
        self.Polish_Flag_btn.pack(side = tk.LEFT, padx = 10)
        self.Polish_Flag_btn.place(y = 350, x = 600)

        self.Italian_Flag = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'ItalianFlag.gif')
        self.Italian_Flag_btn = tk.Button(self.window, image = self.Italian_Flag, command = None)
        self.Italian_Flag_btn.pack(side = tk.LEFT, padx = 10)
        self.Italian_Flag_btn.place(y = 350, x = 900)

    def English_Home_Screen(self):
        self.Eng_self_window = tk.Toplevel(self.window)
        self.Eng_self_window.geometry('1366x768')
        self.Eng_self_window.configure(background = self.Background_Colour)
        self.Eng_self_window.title('Local Languages Learning System')
        #Eng_self.window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        Title1 = tk.Label(self.Eng_self_window, text = 'Local Languages\nEnglish Home Screen', bg = self.Background_Colour)
        Title1.config(font=("Courier", self.Title_Text))
        Title1.pack()
        Title1.place(y = 1, x = 450)

        Log_Out = tk.Button(self.Eng_self_window, text = 'Log-Out', height = 1, width = 8, command = self.LogOut1)
        Log_Out.pack()
        Log_Out.place(y = 5, x = 1290)

        Back = tk.Button(self.Eng_self_window, text = 'Back', height = 1, width = 8, command = self.back1)
        Back.pack()
        Back.place(y = 5, x = 1210)

        help_btn = tk.Button(self.Eng_self_window, text = 'Help', height = 1, width = 8, command = None)
        help_btn.pack()
        help_btn.place(y = 45, x = 1290)

        Play_all = tk.Button(self.Eng_self_window, text = 'Play All Games', height = 2, width = 20, command = None)
        Play_all.pack()
        Play_all.place(y = 100, x = 320)

        Multiple_Choice = tk.Button(self.Eng_self_window, text = 'Play Multiple Choice Game', height = 2, width = 20, command = None)
        Multiple_Choice.pack()
        Multiple_Choice.place(y = 100, x = 510)

        Picture = tk.Button(self.Eng_self_window, text = 'Play Picture Game', height = 2, width = 20, command = None)
        Picture.pack()
        Picture.place(y = 100, x = 700)

        Memory = tk.Button(self.Eng_self_window, text = 'Play Memory Game', height = 2, width = 20, command = None)
        Memory.pack()
        Memory.place(y = 100, x = 890)

        LeaderBoard = tk.Button(self.Eng_self_window, text = 'LeaderBoard', height = 2, width = 20, command = None)
        LeaderBoard.pack()
        LeaderBoard.place(y = 160, x = 600)

    def EngFlag(self):
        print('Hello world')

    def LogOut1(self):
        response = messagebox.askquestion ('?', 'Are You Sure?')
        if response == 'yes':
            if tk.Toplevel.winfo_exists(self.Eng_self_window):
                self.Eng_self_window.destroy()
            else:
                self.window.destroy()

    def back1(self):
        print("Go back")
        self.Eng_self_window.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
Home_Screen(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanyou for your help, the only reason i didnt use a class i because i struggle to understand them, like what does def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent, *args, **kwargs) Mean?

Comment: The `__init__` portion is how the class is initialized. Technically you do not need the `*args, **kwargs` part as they are for extra variables to be submitted to the class if you add more functionality later. You can just use `__init__(self, parent)` here.

Comment: @tom the OOP method can be hard to learn at first but if you work with what I have provided and do a little research as you add to the program it will click eventually. Once it does it will make sense. You can write this in Non_OOP but it will be harder to maintain and require some rearranging of the methods/functions.

Comment: is there anything you would recommend so that I can get a better understanding of classes like books or websites

Comment: @Tom the way I learned was youtube. It was a massive help. And a lot of googling.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help and advise I'm gona get researching it now, any recomended youtube channels

Comment: @tom Socratica is a good place to start. It fun and accurate. It's a YouTube channel.

Comment: I have been learning classes for the last 5 hours and I'm getting the hang of it now, I can realy see the benefits as my code is much more organised and it is much easyer to identify problems in the code. Socratica was a good shout and  stackoverflow.com/q/17466561/7032856 was very useful to in seeing the structure of classes. Thankyou

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: yea sorry I solved it but forgot to remove my comment

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix; [**Don't use multiple instances of `Tk`**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48045401/7032856). Instead, use `Toplevel` and hide & show the `root` window. Add:

```
...
Background_Colour = 'Light blue'

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
...
```

and replace:

```
...
    if response == 'yes':
        try:
         window.destroy()
        except:
         Eng_window.destroy()

...
    global window
    window = Tk()
...
    global Eng_window
    Eng_window = Tk()
```

with:

```
...
    if response == 'yes':
        root.destroy()

...
    global window
    window = Toplevel()
...
    global Eng_window
    Eng_window = Toplevel()
```